# How to get checkboxtreeviewer getselection?

Tags: java, treeview

I have beeen struggling with this method , the problem is that getselection returns the object treeviewer null, thought the object is not empty.. any idea how to solve this?#

Treeviewer is defined here:

```
private CheckboxTreeViewer treeViewer;
```

Used here:

```
ISelection oldSelection = treeViewer.getSelection();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just define `treeViewer` this does not mean it has any value. It has `null` as value. And if you then try to access this variable you get a `NullPointerException` of course. You need to initialize or assign your `treeViewer` variable somewhere.

Comment: I had intialized, it is not written here!!

Comment: Then you provided too few information to be helped. Provide more code, error message, more detail, ...